# Upgrading to Spring 4

Tags: spring, openshift

I have a spring 3 app deployed in openshift jboss eap6, and I want to upgrade to ver 4. I also want to upgrade to Java8. Has anyone here been successful in doing so? What are the things that must be considered?  How can I make the transition easier? I'm so afraid of Jar hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution to your Question**

1. Don't worry Spring 4 is 100% compatible with Java 8
2. For Jars you need to use the **Bill of Materials** of Spring 4 Jars which can be obtained in this [Link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-bom-4.2.4.RELEASE.pom). Use **only these** jars which will take care of your dependencies issues.
3. Typically replace all these JAR files in your WEB Applications and try to build and deploy your application. You got your JAR upgrade if it runs without any issues. Most probably 100% it will run without any issues.
4. Then Depending your scenarios you can apply your spring-framework components.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading von Spring 3.0 to 4.0 could need some changes (depending on what you have done and used). I recommend to do it in small steps, so you can check that everything still works more often, so: uprade to 3.1 first, then 3.2, and then 4.0. After that upgrade to Java 8.

The Spring Reference contain some hints in the what is new section and this Wiki: [Migrating from earlier versions of the Spring Framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-spring-framework)

Attention: if you upgrade Spring Security too, then I strongly recommend to read its upgrade hints in its [Migration documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html)!